# Unauthorised 401 error on azurewebsites.net webapp after integrating Microsoft Identity MSAL. Localhost works

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

My c# webapp on localhost is functional.

However, after publishing to Azure, the website does not display any content and is returned with a 401 unauthorised error.

Reviewing the app's, application event log in azure portal, I see the following error.

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
EventId: 1
RequestId: 80001a7a-0002-f800-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /
SpanId: |51dbc300-47e836e38a7ad2a4.
TraceId: 51dbc300-47e836e38a7ad2a4
ParentId: 

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.AppServicesAuthenticationTokenAcquisition'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetCallSite>b__0(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(PageContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreateModelFactory>b__0(PageContext pageContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.CreateInstance()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

The following refers to the AddAuthetication services in startup.cs

```
    services
       // Use OpenId authentication
       .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       // <AddSignInSnippet>
       // Specify this is a web app and needs auth code flow
       .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
       {
           Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
           options.Prompt = "select_account";
           options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
           { ....
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this error given the two different outcomes for azure hosted and localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not show `IHttpClientFactory` DI and constructor, but most probably, this is happening because of the following reasons:

1. `IHttpClientFactory` is trying to call `AppServicesAuthenticationTokenAcquisition` in the constructor and somehow it is not getting `activated` and then the Dependency Injection(DI) of `IHttpClientFactory` fails.
2. And since authentication is not properly initialized, your app is still making calls to an authenticated API/service which is throwing `401` error.

Comment: Do you know if it matters whether the app was deployed as self-contained and portable in relation to IHttpClientFactory?

Comment: I did not get your question, can you elaborate?